# Помогите решить задачку по Ruby

Tags: ruby

**Напишите программу, которая рекомендует, как одеться сегодня.**

В файлах лежат шмотки в формате:

```
название шмотки
тип шмотки
диапазон температур
```

Например,

```
шапка-ушанка из зайца
шапка
(-20, -5)
```

или

```
шлепанцы
ботинки
(+20, +30)
```

Программа спрашивает у пользователя, какая сейчас температура, а потом генерирует набор одежды, выводит название на экран (в консоль) по одной случайной шмотке каждого типа (если нашлась): `шапка, шарф, кофта, куртка, штаны, ботинки, перчатки.`

**Уточнение:**

Под диапазон может подходить по 2 или 3 шмотки каждого типа например:

```
валенки
ботинки
(-35, -15)

унты
ботинки
(-25, -15)

утепленные кроссовки
ботинки
(-25, -10)
```

и если пользователь введет -18 то выйдет все 3 типа, а нужен 1 случайный тип, нельзя пойти на улицу и надеть на утепленные кроссовки еще валенки сверху.

```
Какая сегодня температура?
-18

Рекомендуется надеть: шапку вязанную, шарф, куртка с мехом, джинсы с начесом, валенки.
```

Чтобы решить задачу я создал класс `ClothesItem`

```
class ClothesItem

  attr_accessor :title, :type, :line

  def initialize(path)
    File.open(path) do |file|
      arr = file.readlines
      @title = arr[0].chomp
      @type = arr[1].chomp
      @line = arr[2].chomp
    end
  end

  def in_interval?(t)
    int1, int2 = @line.gsub(/[() ]/, '').split(',')
    (int1.to_i..int2.to_i).include?(t)
  end
end
```

И вот моя не законченная основная программа (файлы положил в папку clothes)

```
require_relative 'clothes_item'

puts 'Какая сегодня температура?'
temperature = STDIN.gets.chomp.to_i

all_clothes = Array.new

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/data/*.txt"].each do |path|
  all_clothes << ClothesItem.new(path)
end

suit_clothes = Array.new
types_of_clothes = Array.new

all_clothes.each do |c|
  if c.in_interval?(temperature)
    types_of_clothes << c.type
    suit_clothes << [c.title, c.type]
  end
end
```

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы вывести на экран название шмотки 1 случайного типа одежды.

Я только учусь `ruby` знаю как синтаксис знаю много методов но у меня тут как то не хватает логики.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: Vadis, распишите, как сами пытались решить задачу, иначе Вас точно заминусят, а вопрос, возможно, закроют. Спасибо.

Comment: Хорошо попробую сделать  и приложу. И Вам спасибо.

Comment: Неплохое, однако, упражнение на [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html)! Несложное, но содержательное.

Comment: Как только выбрали подходящее по температуре, то потом группируйте их по типу и возьмите по одному рэндомному элементу из каждой группы и получите набор.

Answer (score 4):

Ну ты правильно начал рассуждать. Тебе нужен класс для типа вещи.
Если рассуждать дальше - тебе нужен ещё и класс, для того, чтобы хранить и обрабатывать коллецию. Например такой:

```
class ClothesCollection

  attr_reader :collection

  def initialize(data_folder, item_class)
    @collection = 
      Dir[File.join(data_folder, "*.txt")].map do |item_file|
        item_class.new(item_file)
      end
  end

  def by_temperature(temperature)
    typed_collection.each_value do |type_group|
      type_group
        .find_all { |item| item.in_interval?(temperature) }
        .example
    end
  end

  private  

  def typed_collection
    @typed_collection ||= collection.group_by(&:type)
  end

end
```

Соответсвенно, использовать так:

```
collection =
    ClothesCollection.new(File.expand_path("data", __FILE__), ClothesItem)
collection.by_temperature(-5)
```

Оговорюсь: код далёк от идеала (например вложенные блоки не есть хорошо) и я не проверял его на работоспособность. Это просто пример.

Comment: Спасибо anoam !!! Сам бы я так точно не придумал.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так получилось, не совсем изящно но все же сработало.

```
require_relative 'clothes_item'

puts 'Какая сегодня температура?'
temperature = STDIN.gets.chomp.to_i

all_clothes = Array.new

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/clothes/*.txt"].each do |path|
  all_clothes << ClothesItem.new(path)
end

suit_clothes = Array.new
types_of_clothes = Array.new

all_clothes.each do |c|
  if c.in_interval?(temperature)
    suit_clothes << c
    types_of_clothes << c.type
  end
end

recommended_clothes = Array.new

types_of_clothes.uniq.each do |type|
  for_rand_name = Array.new

  suit_clothes.each do |clothes_item|
    if type == clothes_item.type
      for_rand_name << clothes_item.title
    end
  end

  # для того чтобы не добавлять nil
  unless for_rand_name.empty?
    recommended_clothes << for_rand_name.sample
  end
end

puts "Сегодня, из вашего гардероба рекомендую одеть: #{recommended_clothes.join(', ')}."
```

Сделаю еще 1 класс как предложил `anoam`, думаю это прям будет вообще отлично.